# Resolving classpath-relative paths for non-existing files

Tags: java

I have a project where I'm compiling files to locations relative to `getClass().getResource("/")`. How can I get `File` objects for these locations?

When I try `getClass().getResource("/nonExisting")`, they return null. How can I resolve the paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to expect existent resources to be normal files; they could be buried inside a jar-file somewhere on your classpath.

With non-existent resources, the situation is even worse; even if you could guarantee in the abstract that it *is* a non-existent normal file, it could be a non-existent normal file in any of the top-level directories in your classpath; there's no sensible way to decide which directory it *would* have been in, *had* it existed. (For example, if your classpath contains both `classes` and `testClasses`, then `/nonExisting` could be either `classes/nonExisting` or `testClasses/nonExisting`.)